# getting back negative results in loop

Tags: python

I'm having trouble pinpointing the exact problem in my code. I have two functions- `inrange()`, which checks to see if a port is in range, and `filt()`, which takes a txt file, looks for the keywords "UDP" or "TCP", looks at the port (right after the : mark), and checks to see if that number is within the range or not.

```
def inrange(file,character, num): 
    with open(file, 'r') as r:
        for lines in r:
            for key, value in sshd.items():
                if character == key and character in lines:
                    if num in sshd.get(character):
                        return True
                    else:
                        return False

                elif character == key and character in lines:
                    if num in sshd.get(character):
                        return True
                    else:
                        return False
```

This is specifically for sshd for now.

```
def filt(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as r:
        for i, line in enumerate(r):
            if "sshd"  in line:
                plusOne = i + 1
                newline = line.strip()
                splitIt = newline[7:22]
                my_string = splitIt.split(":", 1)[1]
                if inrange(file, "TCP", int(my_string)):
                    print("Line " + str(plusOne) + " is in range" + " " + my_string)    
                elif inrange(file, "UDP", int(my_string)):
                    print("Line " + str(plusOne) + " is in range" + " " + my_string)     
                else:
                    print("Not in range")
```

Now this works if I have this as my text file-

Active Connections

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  UDP    0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:0             LISTENING       5987  sshd
```

as you can see, UDP 123 is within range if you look at the dictionary `sshd` above. I get a true statement in return. If I change UDP to TCP, it gives me back a negative statement. That works. The problem happens when I add more than one line to this.

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  UDP    0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:0             LISTENING       5987  sshd
  TCP    0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:0             LISTENING       5987  sshd
  UDP    0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:0             LISTENING       5987  sshd
  TCP    0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:0             LISTENING       5987   sshd
```

I get back all positive results:

```
Line 5 is in range 123    
Line 6 is in range 123    
Line 7 is in range 123    
Line 8 is in range 123
```

which shouldn't be the case, as line 6 and line 8 are TCPs in port 123, which is not in range. I feel like I'm missing something clear here. Cant figure it out.

Comment: One quick debugging question - which line of code is doing the printing? Maybe make your `print` calls something like `Line ... is a UDP line in range ...`. That might help pinpoint the error

Comment: Why are the `if` and `elif` sections in the `inrange` function identical?

Comment: @PM2Ring Forgot to scrap that. I added a character input to my inrange function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly look for the string `sshd` line wise, but search the strings `TCP` and `UDP` in the whole file. As there is one line with UDP and 123, every call to `inrange(file, "UDP", int(my_string)):` will return true even if there is a TCP in current line.

You should extract the proto from the current line. Something like

```
    proto = newline[:3]
    if (proto in ['UDP', 'TCP']) and inrange(file, proto, int(my_string)):
        print("Line " + str(plusOne) + " is in range" + " " + my_string)    
    else:
        print("Not in range")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `filt` function checks every port it finds against *both* sets of ranges - I'd suggest rewriting that function to parse out the protocol from the line being read, and pass that variable to `inrange` along with the port number.

A small additional note - in the `inrange` function you're testing the same condition in both the `if` and `elif` branches.