# returning wrong values in file handling function

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a couple functions. `dictionaryValues()` simply returns two dictionaries -- `sshd` and `System`.  The values of both are some numbers in a certain range.

```
def dictionaryValues():
    sshd = {"sshd": (), 
            "UDP": list(itertools.chain(range(593,594), range(1024,5001), range(123,124))),
            "TCP" : list(itertools.chain(range(593,594), range(1024,5001), range(135,136)))
           } 

    System = {"System": (), 
              "TCP": list(itertools.chain(range(445,446), range(139,140), 
                     range(17778,17779), range(3755,3756), range(80, 81), range(5405, 5406))),
              "UDP": list(itertools.chain(range(137,139), range(445, 446)))
             }
    return (sshd, System)
```

My `inrange()` function looks for specific strings in a text file. So for example-

```
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
 TCP    0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:0             LISTENING       1320      System
```

It will look for `TCP` or `UDP` in the text file, then check is `processID` is a key (in this case, System)  in one of the dictionaries in `dictionaryValues()`. If there's a match, it checks to see if `num` is within the range of the values from the dictionary.

```
def inrange(file,character, num):
    with open(file, 'r') as r: 
        for lines in r:
            newline = lines.strip()
            proto = newline[:3] #TCP or UDP
            processID = newline[74:85] #System or sshd
            for x in dictionaryValues():
                for key, value in x.items():
                    if processID in [key]:
                        if character.strip() == "UDP":
                            if num in x.get(character):
                                return True
                            else:
                                return False
                        if character.strip() == "TCP":
                            if num in x.get(character):
                                return True
                            else:
                                return False
```

Lastly, `filt()`, takes the number after the : symbol (in the text example, that would be the number 80 below local address and checks to see if that number is within range.

```
def filt(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as r:
        for i, line in enumerate(r):
            for x in dictionaryValues():
                for key, value in x.items():
                    newline = line.strip()
                    processID = newline[74:85]
                    if processID in [key]:
                        plusOne = i + 1
                        newline = line.strip()
                        splitIt = line[7:22] #gets the number after the : symbol
                        my_string = splitIt.split(":",1)[1]
                        proto = newline[:3]
                        if (proto in ['UDP', 'TCP']) and inrange(file, proto, int(my_string)):
                                print("Line " + str(plusOne) + " is in range" + " " + my_string)
                        else:
                            print(processID + " " + proto + " is not in range " + str(my_string))
```

My problem is that this only works if the text file has one line in the file. If it had multiple lines like

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:0             LISTENING       1320 System
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1230            0.0.0.0:0             LISTENING       1320 sshd
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:0             LISTENING       1320  sshd
  UDP    0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:0             LISTENING       1320 System
```

It would return True for the first line, and False for the next three lines even though the numbers 1230,5000, and 139 are all within range. I think I could be missing something small, just not sure.

Comment: It is the same problem than in your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36155530/3545273): you rescan the whole file for the `inrange` function where you should scan only current line.

Comment: `filt()` will read an parse your file and `inrange()` will do the same; that spells potential misery. The last if statement in `filt()` actually compares the same conditions, so your mistake will be in your `inrange` function; which does not care for several lines - it returns after the evaluation of one line (`return` will break the loop).